# Android EditText align actual text to onDraw positions?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext

When overriding onDraw in an edittext, I can make the text in any location I see fit. What I'm having trouble with is aligning their respective "boxes" ie the area where the actual char is clicked to edit said char. The text I can move, or rather draw wherever, but how do I align the actual physical position of the char to it's painted char? I'm at a bit of a loss I couldn't figure out what to override to change these positions. Any help would be awesome! I don't have any code to post, as it's literally just an extended edittext and override onDraw with a for loop.

I attempted to move the position of text digits individually inside an edit text using onDraw, but found it doesn't seem to move the actual location just the paint representation of it.

EDIT ----------------------------------

Ive found what I believe to be what needs overriden, the onSelection start and end. But, it seems to cause an infinite recursion loop? Anyone got any ideas as to how this is done? Indentation is hard to do on a phone but here's a sample of the rough idea:

```
class HexEditorEditText(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : EditText(context, attrs) {
private val characterWidth: Float
private val characterHeight: Float

init {
    val textPaint = paint
    characterWidth = textPaint.measureText("00")
    characterHeight = textPaint.fontSpacing
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    val text = text.toString()
    var x = 0f
    var y = 0f
    for (i in 0 until text.length step 2) {
        val pair = text.substring(i, i + 2)
        canvas?.drawText(pair, x, y, paint)
        x += characterWidth + characterWidth / 2
    }
}

override fun getSelectionStart(): Int {
    val layout = layout
    val line = layout.getLineForOffset(selectionStart)
    val x = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(selectionStart)
    return (x / (characterWidth + characterWidth / 2)).toInt() * 2
    }

override fun getSelectionEnd(): Int {
    val layout = layout
    val line = layout.getLineForOffset(selectionEnd)
    val x = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(selectionEnd)
    return (x / (characterWidth + characterWidth / 2)).toInt() * 2
    }

override fun setSelection(start: Int, stop: Int) {
    super.setSelection((start / 2) * 2, (stop / 2) * 2)
    }
}
```